# How to get json data from url and save it to the const variable [TypeScript]

Tags: javascript, json, typescript, ecmascript-6

How to get `json` data from `url` and save them into the const variable in `TypeScript`?

```
const data = (get json from url);
```

Output:

```
data = [
                {
                    "name": "Peter",
                    "age": "20"
                },
                {
                    "name": "John",
                    "age": "25"
                }
            ];
```

Comment: to my knowledge, a `const` variable cant be changed after it is initialised. you would need to use `var`

Comment: The internal state of a `const` variable is still modifiable in TypeScript.
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/variable-declarations.html

Comment: as quoted, `const is an augmentation of let in that it prevents re-assignment to a variable`

Comment: @mast3rd3mon
`const numLivesForCat = 9; 
const kitty = {     name: "Aurora",     numLives: numLivesForCat, }  // Error kitty = {     name: "Danielle",     numLives: numLivesForCat };  // all "okay" kitty.name = "Rory"; kitty.name = "Kitty"; kitty.name = "Cat"; kitty.numLives--;`

Comment: maybe so, but thats not what you are trying to do

Answer (score 9):

**You can use fetch API , here's the sample**

I've use a dynamic variable , since constant cannot be re-assigned once the response is generated.

```js
   let data  = ''

 fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments')
  .then(function(response) {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then(function(myJson) {

    data=myJson
 console.log(data)
  });
```

hope this helps you :)